# Python3 code issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

## I'm lost on what my issue is. This is what comes up in terminal and I get a csv with no information.

$ python3 test1.py

LIST -->

Scraping

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "test1.py", line 162, in <module>

search_bing(i)

File "test1.py", line 131, in search_bing

driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linkedin+" + n + "&t=hb&ia=web")

File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 264, in get

self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute

self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in 
check_response

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":
{"frameId":"40864.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}

(Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)
```

## Full script below. You can ignore the enter group code as the HTML from the website I am scraping goes there and it was to long for this post.

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

c = csv.writer(open("linkedin-group-results.csv", "w"))
c.writerow(["Member","Profile"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')


your_groups_code = """

#enter group code here
"""

users = []
ul = []
def search_bing(name):
n = name.replace(" ", "+")
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linkedin+" + n + "&t=hb&ia=web")
time.sleep(3)
s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
fr = s.find("div", class_="result__body links_main links_deep")

for a in fr.find_all('a'):
    try:
        if 'linkedin.com/in' in a['href']:
            print ('found linkedin url'), a['href']
            if a['href'] in ul:
                print ('skipping dup')
            else:
                ul.append(a['href'])
                c.writerow([name, a['href']])
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print (e,'..continue')


soup = BeautifulSoup(your_groups_code, 'lxml')
for a in soup.find_all('img'):
name = a['alt']
if name in users:
    print ('skipping dup')
else:
    users.append(name)

if len(users) > 1:
print ('LIST -->'), users
for i in users:
    print ("Scraping"), i
    search_bing(i)
else:
print ('Congrats! Your making progress.. Now please insert the code of 
the linkedin group you want to scrape (as seen in tutorial)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using an older version of ChromeDriver, 2.9 , which is most likely not compatible with Chrome 58. Please download and try the latest version, 2.29 .
See notes : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt

Comment: Updating chromedriver seemed to fix the issue and worked on a test. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've stripped out a lot of your code, so it's hard to debug. From what I can tell, your code is failing in the search_bing() method when you call driver.get(). I tried a simple version of this code and it works, so I suggest you figure out if there's something wrong with the 'name' var you're passing in to search_bing().

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

c = csv.writer(open("linkedin-group-results.csv", "w"))
c.writerow(["Member","Profile"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

name = 'John Smith'
n = name.replace(" ", "+")
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linkedin+" + n + "&t=hb&ia=web")
```